# Sequelize fails with permission denied for database, when config property migrationStorageTableSchema is set

Tags: node.js, postgresql, permissions, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using sequelize to run migrations on my DB, the user has all privileges and migrations work well, however it creates SequelizeMeta table in a public schema. When I set schema in the config with `migrationStorageTableSchema` migrations fail with:

> permission denied for database blabla

Comment: Do you run **sequelize init** command?

Comment: @RiajulIslam The project is relatively old legacy code, just got it to support. Judging to the directory structure it wasn't bootstrapped with init command or was with the older version of it. The migrations run with the following command: sequelize db:migrate --config ./src/database/config/staging.js --migrations-path ./src/database/migrations --seeders-path ./src/database/seeders --models-path ./src/database/models

Comment: The problem was in missing searchPath: solved with ALTER DATABASE blabla SET search_path = schema_name